# Is there a way of accepting only specific words in edit text?

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.2

Not expecting it will work at all, but quite new to Android Studio, Basically i'm entering text into a text box and then submitting it via alertDialogboxes. Is there a way of only accepting for example the word money or food, no other text entered apart from one of those words allowed to be submitted?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could do something with a TextWatcher.  But what do you do if someone enters a bad word-  delete it?  Stop them from typing it at all?  Neither works really well.  You may be better off with a spinner, unless you need multiple words to be entered.

Comment: you can retreive string from edittext and then check through loop of arrays whether the string matches your predefined list of words, if it does then sumbit

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I had radio buttons in to accept a specific choice but i couldn't get them to show in the alert dialog message so changed to a text box. 
How would i go about checking through a loop of arrays? As i say i am pretty new to Android Studio so i'm not a strong programmer, thanks